# Is "pejorative" used correctly in "no pejorative bone in his body"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, figurative

> He doesn't have a pejorative bone in his body.

This is meant to describe a timid, non-confrontational person. Is *pejorative* being used correctly here, in a figurative sense?

Comment: Yes. It's specifically saying they don't like to be critical.

Comment: No - *pejorative* here is being used ***literally***. It's the non-existent *bone in his body* that's figuratively standing in for *aspect of his personality*.

Answer (score 2):

In general, any adjective that describes a person's personality can be used in the phrase

```
no _________ bone in his body
```

This is a metaphoric way of saying that the adjective doesn't apply to the person.

However, *pejorative* is not usually used to describe a person, it's generally used to describe a a word or the way a word is used.  A better word to describe such a person would be *critical*.

With that said, the phrase would still be understood easily, as indicating that the person does not normally make pejorative comments.

Comment: I agree with what you say except for the last sentence.  I don't agree that the phrase will be easily understood, and don't agree it indicates the person normally doesn't make pejorative comments.

Comment: What else could it mean?